# Disable button on form load

Tags: c#, forms, button

I'm begginer in `C#` and i have 2 forms, in both are buttons. I would like to click a `button` in `form1` and on that button click I would like to make button in `form2` `unclickable` or `disabled` but still `visible`. Is there any easy or understandable way which would work for sure?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Is there a relationship between the 2 forms? I.e. is Form1 the parent of Form2?

Comment: Do you open Form2 from Form1? If so, i would store the instance as field in form1, then you can use that to access properties or methods in Form2. So you could  provide a public method `public void EnableButton(bool enabled){this.ButtonXY.Enabled = enabled;}`

Comment: Yes, Form1 is opening Form2

Comment: In that case the example from Fire Dragon should provide exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's not hard, you must ensure to have a reference to the instance of form2 in form1, or directly a reference to the button of form2 instance.

An example could be (consider it pseudocode, not a complete one):

```
class MyForm1
{
    public MyForm2 Form2 { get; set; }

    protected OnButton1Clicked()
    {
        Form2.ToggleButton();
    }
}
class MyForm2
{
    public ToggleButton()
    {
        button2.Enabled = !button2.Enabled;
    }
}

// Main
form1 = new MyForm1();
form1.Form2 = new MyForm2();
```